# Where to put the async/unblocking in mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, asynchronous

Many of the commands/events (just about everything other then a small amount of pure object changes) need to be run in a non-blocking fashion to stop the application from freezing.

Should the unblocking code(Background Worker/Task/etc.) generally go in the model, the viewmodel, or the view?

Comment: In MVVM there is no controller.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, You can use async tools (Backworker,Thread/Task ..) in you Commands and ViewModels as well, but not in your models. Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123183/Asynchronus-MVVM-Stop-the-Dreaded-Dead-GUI-Problem)

 Events are rarely involved in MVVM, especially at implementing business logic since they cannot have a direct relation with the ViewModel unless you use Events to Commands tools.

Comment: By events I mean raising events such as clicked instead of using commands, And the viewmodel/model methods are being called from the view, they don't have a direct relation but you can still put async in the bottom layers(but is that a good idea is what I'm asking).

Comment: By knowing each pattern member's role you can define what sounds a good idea and what's not. The link provided will help you on that.

Answer (score 1):

The task should be started asynchronously either in the ViewModel or in the Model, certainly not in the View.

I would make it a context related decision. Is asnychronous calculation of something an intrinsic feature of your business logic that has complex interdependencies within the business logic? Then put the 'unblocking code' in the model. Then you need to implement accoridng events to inform your ViewModel when the task has been accomplished, or more generally speaking, your Model has changed (as a sidemark: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the Model is perfectly legitimate here).

If you want to keep your model clean of asnychronous stuff, start it from the ViewModel. You have to be very careful though, to not run into issues, when you asynchronously modify your model. I would lock it.

BTW: Have a look at the Task Parallel Library. You could write an Execute() method for a command like this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                
   return expensiveTaskResults();
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
   if (t.IsFaulted) HandleError(t);                
   Result = t.Result;
}
```

Nice and simple.

This might provide some more information: [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989684/busyindicator-allows-to-fire-relaycommand-twice)

Comment: Because you want to keep your View clean of anything which is not the View... Doing stuff asnychronously is definitely something potentially complicated, you want to test, etc... The View should care neither about what tasks are performed behind the scenes, nor how. And what you want to do, is part of the How? question, I would say.